# Выборочный показ видео с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Нужна помощь по jQuery. Меня такая вот проблема. Вообщем, сходу на странице появляются 10 видео, должно показывать только одно. По клику на кнопку видео №1 исчезает и появляется видео № 2 и т. д. до 10. Пробовал двумя разными способами, ни один не работает. Вот способы:

```
$('iframe:not(iframe:first)').hide();
//оставляем видимым только 1е видео

function toMas(j) //функция создает массив из всех элементов выборки 
{ // j - параметр для выбора элемента массива объектов
    var arrayOfFilms = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $('iframe').size(); i++)
    //проходим в цикле по всем элементам    выборки jq
    {
        arrayOfFilms[i] = $('iframe').get(i); //i-му элементу массива присваиваем i-e значение выборки :)
    }
    return arrayOfFilms[j]; // возвращаем видео по номеру
}

var sposob_1 = 1;

var sposob_2 = 1;
$('#next').click(function () //когда нажимаем на кнопку 
{
    $('iframe:first').hide(); //первое видео гаснет

    var YYY = toMas(sposob_1); // переменной YYY присваиваем полученую выборку

    alert(YYY); // проверяем, выводит object html iframe element, все нормально
    YYY.show(); // а вот тут происходит нечто, ничего не работает(

    var FFF = $('iframe').get(sposob_2); // пробуем другим способом
    alert(FFF); // выводит object html iframe element, все норм
    FFF.show(); // и тут не выводит, не знаю что делать 
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. )

Answer (score 2):

Наверное надо

```
$($('iframe').get(sposob_2)).show();
```

либо

```
$(YYY).show();
```

Фишка в том что Вы берёте **DOM Объект** а считаете что он **jquery** объект.

[.get( [index] )](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

можно наверное ещё посмотреть селектор [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).